# One way bouncycastle TLS client server sets up successfully but won't send or receive data Java

Tags: java, multithreading, ssl

I have written a simple TLS server and client using basically the same code offered in the "Java Cryptography Tools and Techniques" the server successfully accepts the client but there must be an issue with the connection because whenever I try to send data from the client to the server the client hangs. The same is true if I call SSLSocket.startHandshake() so there must be a handshake issue. As I mentioned however all of the Server and Client code is basically guaranteed to be correct. I have looked into the code which generates the Certificate but cannot see any issue with it I have no idea whats wrong and its driving me nuts. It has nothing to to with the ordering of the ObjectInputStream and its counterpart by the way. This is the Server code:

```
public class ServerTask implements Runnable {

private KeyStore serverStore;
private char[] passwd;

public ServerTask(KeyStore serverStore, char[] passwd) {
    this.serverStore = serverStore;
    this.passwd = passwd;
}

    public void run() {
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3", "BCJSSE");

            KeyManagerFactory keyMgrFact = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
                    "PKIX", "BCJSSE");
            keyMgrFact.init(serverStore, passwd);

            sslContext.init(keyMgrFact.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

            SSLServerSocketFactory fact = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
            SSLServerSocket sSock = (SSLServerSocket) fact.createServerSocket(2048);

            SSLSocket sslSock = (SSLSocket) sSock.accept();

            try (DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sslSock.getInputStream()))) {
                String test =input.readUTF();
                System.out.println();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the client code:

```
public class ClientTask implements Runnable {

private KeyStore trustStore;

public ClientTask(KeyStore trustStore){
    this.trustStore = trustStore;
}

public void run(){
    try
    {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3", "BCJSSE");
        TrustManagerFactory trustMgrFact =
                TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX", "BCJSSE");
        trustMgrFact.init(trustStore);
        sslContext.init(null, trustMgrFact.getTrustManagers(), null);
        SSLSocketFactory fact = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket cSock = (SSLSocket)fact.createSocket("localhost", 2048);

        try (DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(cSock.getOutputStream()))) {
            output.writeUTF("feck dis");
            System.out.println("dd");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Main has this code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
          final String PROVIDER = "BC";
          final String KEYSTORE_TYPE = "PKCS12";
          KeyStore keyStore1, trustStore2;
          Phaser phaser = new Phaser();

        String name1 = "localhost", name2 = "client";
        KeyPair kp1 = SecurityUtilities.generateKeyPair();
        X509Certificate cert1 = SecurityUtilities.makeV1Certificate(kp1.getPrivate(), kp1.getPublic(), name1);

        keyStore1 = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE, PROVIDER);
        trustStore2 = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE, PROVIDER);


        keyStore1.load(null, null);
        keyStore1.setKeyEntry(name1, kp1.getPrivate(), null, new X509Certificate[]{cert1});


        trustStore2.load(null, null);
        trustStore2.setCertificateEntry(name2, cert1);

        Thread server = new Thread(new ServerTask(keyStore1, "relaypass".toCharArray()));
        Thread client = new Thread(new ClientTask(trustStore2));

        server.start();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        client.start();
        System.out.println();

    }catch (GeneralSecurityException | OperatorCreationException | IOException | InterruptedException e){}
}
```

Finally the methods which build the certificate and get the keypair are as follows:

```
public class SecurityUtilities {

private static final String ASYMMETRIC_KEY_ALG = "RSA";
private static final String PROVIDER = "BC";
private static final String SIGNATURE_ALG = "SHA384with" + ASYMMETRIC_KEY_ALG;
private static final String SECURE_RANDOM_ALG = "SHA1PRNG";

private static long serialNumberBase = System.currentTimeMillis();

static{
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider());
}

/**
 * Generate an RSA keypair
 * @return return the keypair
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException
 */
public static KeyPair generateKeyPair()
        throws GeneralSecurityException
{
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ASYMMETRIC_KEY_ALG, PROVIDER);
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(3072, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4));
    return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
}



/**
 * Generate a self signed V1 X509Certificate for use by the server to authenticate and sign new users into the network
 * it pertains to.
 * @param caPrivateKey The private key for use in signing
 * @param caPublicKey the public key of the certificate
 * @param name The name of the self signing party
 * @return The Certificate
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException
 * @throws OperatorCreationException
 */
public static X509Certificate makeV1Certificate(PrivateKey caPrivateKey, PublicKey caPublicKey, String name)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, OperatorCreationException
{

    X509v1CertificateBuilder v1CertBldr = new JcaX509v1CertificateBuilder(
            new X500Name("CN=" + name),
            calculateSerialNumber(),
            calculateDate(0),
            calculateDate(24 * 365 * 100),
            new X500Name("CN=" + name),
            caPublicKey);

    JcaContentSignerBuilder signerBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(SIGNATURE_ALG).setProvider(PROVIDER);
    return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(PROVIDER).getCertificate(v1CertBldr.build(signerBuilder.build(caPrivateKey)));
}


/**
 * A date utilitiy for calculating how much time in the future a certificate will be valid for
 * @param hoursInFuture the number of hours you want the certificate to be valid for
 * @return the Date of that number of hours in the future from the current time
 */
private static Date calculateDate(int hoursInFuture){

    long secs = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

    return new Date((secs + (hoursInFuture * 60 * 60)) * 1000);
}

/**
 * A method for soliciting a distinct serial number for certificate generation for multiple threads
 * @return the SerialNumber
 */
private static synchronized BigInteger calculateSerialNumber(){
    return BigInteger.valueOf(serialNumberBase++);
}
```

I have been over every article I could find on what the problem could be but cannot find any reason why the handshake here should fail. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your client writes small data to a buffered stream without flushing or closing, so nothing is actually sent on the socket, and your server never receives anything. (The handshake isn't failing -- that would cause an exception; it isn't being done at all due to the lack of any data.) You need to file a claim on your 'basic guarantee'.

Comment: Actually I have tried it with flush(), it hangs when its called and these are try with resource blocks so they close automatically. Anything else?

Comment: It turns out it wasn't hanging but takes like nearly two minutes to execute. This is probably because bouncycastle library code takes literal minute to run in debug mode.